# is there any java/spring way to store session information for the current logged user using the HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am wondering if I can set attributes on the `HttpServletRequest` object.

What I want to do is to store some information for the current logged user that I can later get back (on the same session).

I am using spring mvc.

So far I tried this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test1(final HttpServletRequest req, final ModelMap model) {
    List<String> myList = (List<String>)req.getAttribute("myList");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/url2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test2(final HttpServletRequest req, final ModelMap model) {
    String message = "hello world";
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    messages.add(messages);
    req.setAttribute("myList", messages);
}
```

So far, when I make the `req.getAttribute` I get a null... Any idea?

Comment: Is there something wrong with [`HttpServletRequest.getSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29)?

Comment: Exactly. Set there some key/value for logged user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `setAttribute` in `session` should be used like this:

```
 request.getSession().setAttribute("myList", messages);
```

And you can get it like this :

```
 request.getSession().getAttribute("myList");
```

Comment: thank you! and how could I get this info back? same way?

Comment: `request.getSession().getAttribute("myList");`

Comment: awesome! sorry, is there any way to set an expiration time?

Comment: @jpganz18 it will expire when the session is discarded. If you want more 'advanced' session persistence look into the spring-session project.